# Exclude table's data from another table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Is it possible to create a query and ask the following?
I have two tables (each one has one column with data) and I want to obtain as a result all data from the first table MINUS the data from the second table.

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL you could do that very easily with EXCEPT:

```
SELECT
  Column1
FROM
  Table1

EXCEPT

SELECT
  Column2
FROM
  Table2;
```

However, EXCEPT is unsupported in MS Access. Instead, you could use an *anti-join*. There are various ways of implementing an anti-join. One is using an EXISTS predicate:

```
SELECT
  Column1
FROM
  Table1 AS t1
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      Table2 AS t2
    WHERE
      t1.Column1 = t2.Column2
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround that works with Access is to use a `LEFT JOIN` on the criteria that the ID variable in the exclusion table `IS NULL`

```
SELECT IDvar
    FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.IDvar = Table2.IDvar
    WHERE Table2.IDvar IS NULL;
```